# Why did Ouda translate wrong in Ace Ventura 2?

Tags: ace-ventura-pet-detective

In "Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls", Ace visits the aggressive Wachootoo tribe and angers them when his Wachati guide (Ouda) incorrectly translates his peaceful message into a hostile declaration.

> **Ace:** Tell them what I'm saying. I come in peace!
>
> **Ouda:** [*in Wachootoo*] White Devil say, "I will harm you." [*the Wachootoo get angry*]
>
> **Ace:** [*to Ouda*] I couldn't help but notice the "equinsu ocha" part. Did you just refer to me as "white devil"?
>
> **Ouda:** This is how they know you.
>
> **Ace:** Leave that part out from now on! [*to the Wachootoo*] I represent the princess!
>
> **Ouda:** [*in Wachootoo*] "I am a Princess." [*the Wachootoo look surprised. One smiles at Ace*]
>
> **Ace:** War is hell. The last thing we want... is a fight!
>
> **Ouda:** [*in Wachootoo*] "I want to fight, so go to hell." [*The Wachootoo start yelling*]

Ouda is his ally throughout the movie and seems to have no issues translating Wachootoo at any other time except this one scene.

**Why did Ouda translate wrong in Ace Ventura 2? Was it on accident or on purpose?**

Comment: long time since I watched it... perhaps Ouda is just a bad translator that is not actually fluent in the language? When else is he seen translating Wachootoo for Ace? Also: comedic effect, it's not a serious movie

Comment: @Luciano - he translates for Ace throughout several scenes following that one without any issues. I realize it's probably just for comedic effect, but it seems like an awfully specific "poor" translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We don't know for sure.

TV Tropes suggests that Ouda is either trying to help Ace, or might just be trolling:

(Warning: TV Tropes link)

[Trolling Translator](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/AceVentura): Ace gets his Wachati guide Ouda to translate his words into the Wachootoo language...badly.

> **Ace**: War Is Hell. The last thing we want is a fight.
>
> **Ouda**: "I want a fight, so go to hell!"
>
> It's left to the viewers' imagination whether Ouda is actually a bad translator, or if he's working to keep Ace alive with his mistranslations; the Wachootoo don't seem like peace-loving people, and might take fatal offense to Ace's cowardice.
>
> Though, given that at one point he has Ace calling himself a princess, Ouda is likely either genuinely bad or a giant Troll.

As the Wachati appear to enjoy fighting it does seem likely that Ouda, believing that Ace is capable enough, needs to be pushed into observing the customs and traditions of the tribe in order to get what he wants.

There is a novelisation for the film, that may contain the answer. I tried to search within the book, but was unable to preview the full pages. You can find more about the book here: [Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5oq-JzLGLPEC&q)